# Assign enum member to void pointer?

Tags: c++

I have a void pointer that has to hold some information and there I wanted to assign it to a int based on my enumeration. I want this integer to be available through all the time so that the void pointer isn't pointing to "garbage".
Here is the code:

```
enum type {nc, ns, nd};

void* thatType;

thatType = &nc
```

The outcome of this, is that I get this error: expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
So is "nc" an actual variable or does it just work like a placeholder for the integer of 0?
 If I then did this:

```
thatType = (int*)nc
```

First of all, why does this not give me an error then?

Comment: c-cast is very permissive, and can really be misused. prefer c++ cast which are less permissive.

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: @asd: See my answer.

Comment: Why are you not just doing `type thatType;`?

Comment: Because that I do not want to change the type specifier, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are two very different things.

```
&nc
```

This is trying to take the address of an enumerator, but enumerators aren't objects and don't have addresses. It's like trying to write `&42` to get the address of the literal `42`. Only string literals have addresses (more or less).

---

```
(int*)nc
```

This, on the other hand, is taking the integer value of `nc` (which is `0`) and converting it to a pointer. Basically you're writing `(int*)nullptr`. That's legal, though questionable (which is why, of the C++ casts, only a `reinterpret_cast` will compile here).

Notice in particular that you did not write `(int*)&nc`.

---

> does it just work like a placeholder for the integer of 0?

Basically, yes, that's right.

Comment: thanks man! You say "Basically, yes, that's right.", so it there something more technical behind this or? and should i use static or dynamic cast for these things? Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: and why do you have to specify "nc" as a int pointer in order to make it work? doesn't the compiler know that it is an int, when it is an integer? you also say "and converting it to a pointer" so what is it pointing to? :/ I know, many questions :(

Comment: _"should i use static or dynamic cast for these things?"_ You haven't actually said what you're trying to do, but my advice is not to do it.

Comment: _"what is it pointing to"_ Nothing. You took the integer `0` and made it into a [null] pointer. That the value `0` started off its life in an enum is basically irrelevant.

Comment: _"why do you have to specify "nc" as a int pointer in order to make it work?"_ You don't. If you wish to encode data into the value of a pointer (not advisable, but I realise that this does happen sometimes) then a `(void*)` will be fine.

Comment: So when (int*)0 creates a null pointer, what does (int*)1 point to? I mean it cannot point to a location that haven't been created right?

Comment: @asd: Right, in reality it's almost certainly an invalid pointer. But it "theoretically" points to some `int` living at memory address 0x1.